# Can uDeploy take care of automating Windows MSI Build?

Tags: jenkins, urbancode, udeploy

I have a wpf application where we are outputting as MSI. I am planning to move this build to uDeploy. Is it possible for uDeploy to take care of build process of generating MSI fom my C#/WPF source code?

Answer (score 0):

In IBM UrbanCode Deploy you do not have a feature out of the box that will help you to create MSI package. There is a plugin available but it only allows you to execute, install and uninstall MSI.

To build MSI package you will have to use a command line and invoke this script from uDeploy using Shell Scripting step. Another way how you can do it is building your own uDeploy plugin that will create MSI packages.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is write a shell script and invoke that script

Answer (score 0):

In general UDeploy is for deployment only - not for builds. Urbancode Build could easily do this with the MSBuild plugin: https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/plugin/msbuild-ubuild/